# list strings alphabetically, but not from first character

Tags: python, text

I'm new to python and was wondering:

Is there a way to sort a list of strings alphabetically for any given character not just the first?

For example:

['gate','venue,'dog','gate']

...

['gate','dig','dog','venue']

'gate' comes first because it contains an 'a' and no other string has a letter that comes before 'a' and 'dig' comes next because it has an 'd' and no other string has a letter that comes before 'd', and so on.

I'll ultimately want to do this with lists containing Japanese characters, not sure if that makes a difference.

Thanks in advance

Comment: and how to handle in case of tie ?

Comment: good point, I guess I don't care how its sorted after. could it be random?

Comment: In the case of Japanese characters, sorting will probably be based on 五十音順.

Comment: right. is there a way I can make it so it ignores hirgana/katakana?

Comment: @DanKelman Hey, I edited and removed "thanks in advanced" as it was inappropriate. Nothing personal, I was just doing my job to help the community. As you did [here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7697778). You need not take a revenge by editing my top answers and adding the same "thanks in advanced". Your suggested edit would anyway be rejected. Anyway, take it easy mate. Don't take it personal. We are all here to share and learn, and it is all part of community learning and sharing. Some of us spend some time to improvise the posts by editing them.

Comment: I felt it was uncalled for. It was a appropriate and polite to thank people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> a = ['dog','gate','venue','dig']
>>> a.sort(key=lambda x:min(x))
>>> print a
>>> ['gate', 'dog', 'dig', 'venue']
```

`gate` on #1 because it contains `a` which gets highest precedence , then `dog` because of `d` and `venue` because of `e` and so on ...